# Matlab formula equation editor GUI

Tags: matlab, equation, solver

How i can execute an equation from GUI?
Example:
[image]
How i can do this with various type of equation?

Thanks the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I *think* you want to grab the equation that a user types in to a text box and turn it in to a function?

Why does your `F` change from 3 arguments to 4? i.e. `F(x,y,y') --> F(1,0,5,-1)` in the next line? (The examples of F you gave don't seem to match up with your equation..)

In any case, check out `eval()`, perhaps that is what you want.
It takes in a matlab command as a string, e.g. `2 + 3`, and evalutes it.

So

```
eval('2+3') % gives 5
eval('f=@(x,y,ydash) y*sqrt(1+ydash^2)')  % gives a function f
f(1,5,-2) % gives 11.1803
```

But in any case, how do you expect the user to type in the square root symbol and the squared symbol? The `eval()` approach relies on them typing in syntax that matlab will understand.

If you clarify your question a bit more this will be easier.

Comment: sorry, F(1,0,5,-1) means this F(1,0.5,-1)

Comment: y' (ydash) means y derivative

Comment: Yes, I am aware of what a derivative is. If it was `F(x,y,y') = F(1,0.5,-1)` -- how on earth does `y*sqrt(1+(y')^2) == (0.5)*sqrt(1+(-1)^2) = 7`?!

Comment: this is just an example sorry for that, thanks for the solution